# Why VSCode shows strange "@number" (like int[10]@9) for arrays when debugging?

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code

This was a simple binary search code and while I was debugging it for my better understanding, I got this remark `a = int[10]@9` in the debugging panel - what does it mean (especially "@9" part after the type)?
[image: int[10]@9 remark while debugging]

```
/**
 * BinarySearch
 */
public class BinarySearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[]={1,3,5,14,22,37,54,77,99,110},target=99 ;
        System.out.println(binarysearch(a,target)); 
    }
    static int binarysearch(int a[], int target)
    {
        int s=0,e=a.length-1;
        int mid;
        while(s<=e)
        {
            mid=s+e/2; //mid= 4 
            if(target<a[mid]) //false
            e=mid-1;//
            else if(target > a[mid])//true
            s=mid+1;
            else if(a[mid]==target) {
            return mid;
            }

        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can accept the answer if it solved your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the debugger shows the toString() value of an object.
As arrays don't override the toString() method, it just uses the default implementation inherited from `Object`.

As the documentation says [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()), the string is constructed in the following way:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

So, that's exactly what you're seeing: the class name, the '@' symbol, and the hash code.

Comment: While true, the `getClass().getName()` part of `toString()` represents `int[]` type via `[I` for instance `[I@b81eda8` not via `int[10]` which looks more like `arrayType[arrayLength]`. So it is not *result* of `toString()` but of some other mechanism used by debugger.

Comment: and the number on the given screenshot after the `@` is most probably not the hashcode - `@9` is too small for that, it is more like the [uniqueID](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/jdk.jdi/com/sun/jdi/ObjectReference.html#uniqueID()) used by JDI

Comment: OK, then when the value of `@<Something>` is the same for two variables, it means that it is referencing the same value in memory?

Answer (score 4):

Some debuggers annotate objects with an *additional* unique number reflecting the "identity" of the object, so you can easily tell if two different references are referencing the same object, versus two objects with the same values.  This is not always the "identity hash code" referred to in the other answer, but can e.g. refer to "this was the Nth object allocated" in a test scenario.